Проверка на сообщения в лс бота
Можно ли сделать проверку, чистый чат в лс бота и пользователя или нет?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Telegram API не предусмотрел возможности получать всю переписку боту, соответственно, ни одна библиотека, которая реализует API для бота, тоже не предоставляет такие методы.
Можно самостоятельно записывать взаимодействие бота с пользователем, используя любую базу данных. И уже на основе таких данных определять.
Также вы можете использовать метод getChat, который позволяет получить информацию о пользователе, если он взаимодействовал с ботом и пользователь не заблокировал бота. Вот документация этого метода в aiogram 3.
